# Finding angle in circle to produce equal areas

Tags: geometry, trigonometry, triangles, circles, angle

I have a circle that is divided into 4 quadrants with a vertical and a horizontal axis.

The center of the circle (where the axes cross) is point *b*.

The top of the vertical axis is point *d*.

On the horizontal axis, to the left of *b* is point *a*.

A line is drawn from *a* diagonally up and to the right, across the vertical axis (at point *c*) and meets the top right of the circle at *e*.

Line *be* and point *f* (the right end of the horizontal axis) have been added to help with the solution.

[image]

The radius of the circle is 30 and the x position of point *a* is -.5 from *b*, taking *b* to be (0, 0) (that is, *a* is to the left of *b* by .5)

**How would we go about calculating $ \angle eab$ so that $\triangle cab$ = slanty sector *dce*?**

With trial and error in a graphing program, I found the answer to be 88.09075925431...

But how would one go about solving this in a general method?

Comment: Did you try instead sector $bed$ and triangle $abe$?

Comment: @TedShifrin Is that any easier?

Comment: Yes, although you're still going to need to use trigonometry and will end up with an equation like $a\cos\theta = b\theta$ to solve numerically. I just worked it out, and your angle is approximately $88.0905^\circ$. The natural angle to use in the problem as I posed it is $\angle dbe$.

Comment: If you know some calculus (i.e., Taylor polynomials), you can solve that equation approximately by solving a quadratic polynomial. No numerical solution needed.

Comment: Where did you get this question? Perhaps that will help me (or others) decide if there could possibly be a different approach from the one I've taken.

Comment: I'm trying to compare the elliptical path of the earth with Ptolemy's system (specifically as explained in Maimonedes). The Earth's eccentricity is currently measured as about .01671, which I've approximated in this equation as 1/61. At this stage in the calculations, I've inflated the ellipse into a circle, and am trying to find the expected delay of the sun's position after 1/4 of the year has passed since perihelion (based on Kepler's equal areas) before deflating the circle again. The Earth is point e (or the Sun, in Ptolemy's), the Sun is point a. I think I'm out of characters...

Comment: Oh, I see. It's a reasonable astronomical question to ask, and no reason to suppose the solution will not involve trigonometry and a transcendental (non-algebraic) equation. Can you work out the trigonometry from my suggestion? As I said, I used as variable $\theta$ the angle $dbe$ and then converted over to your angle $eab$ at the end using the law of cosines and law of sines.

Comment: Once I get this angle, I will use 1/the arctan of it as the distance (in Ptolemy's epicycles) from the Earth to the Perihelion (or more aptly to Apogee), and the distance from that point to the Sun is 1 (unity), and once that's set up, I can compare both systems for any given point in Earth's orbit.

Comment: I meant to say that I've approximated the eccentricity as 1/60 (and not 1/61).

Answer (score 1):

Here is an outline of the solution:

Let $\theta = \angle dbe$, *in radians*. Then we get the area of the sector to be $900\pi\cdot\frac{\theta}{2\pi} = 450\theta$. And the area of $\triangle abe$ is $\frac12 (ab)(be)\sin(\frac\pi 2+\theta) = \frac{15}2\cos\theta$. Setting these equal, we get the equation
$$60\theta = \cos\theta.$$
We can solve this numerically (e.g., Newton's method) or by using the second-order Taylor polynomial of $\cos$ and the quadratic formula. Either way, we get $\theta\approx 0.0166644$.

Now you can use standard trigonometry (e.g., law of cosines and law of sines) to find your angle $eab$ to be approximately $1.53747$ radians, or $88.0905^\circ$.

Comment: First of all thanks for your answer. I see that it's simpler doing it your way as the way I was doing it ended up as (90 - asin((sin(x)*(cos(asin(sin(x)*.5/30))*30+cos(x)*.5))/30)) / 360 * pi 900 - (tan(x)*cos(asin((sin(x)*(cos(asin(sin(x)*.5/30))*30+cos(x)*.5))/30))) * 7.5 = .125 tan(x) and I didn't really know how to simplify that. But I see we got the same answer so that's good. Why did you measure the height of the triangle by adding 90 degrees and then taking the sine? Why didn't you just take the cosine of the angle right away? I followed your method until you got to Newton's... (cont..)

Comment: (...continued) ... method. I have no idea about that stuff. I just plug in the two sides of the equation into a graph program and zoom in to where the lines meet. I also did your method but with degrees and got: 3 * cos(x) = pi * x, which is waaaaaay simpler than what I had done, so kudos.

Comment: You cannot do degrees. You must use radians and convert to degrees at the very end.